# Rectangular Rule(Numerical Integration using C++

Tags: c++, numeric, subroutine, numerical-integration

I am trying to do numerical integration(rectangular rule using subroutine), this is my code for now, it still got some problem referring to data type i guess(maybe), please help me to complete the code and make it functional to be used. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
#define Pi 3.142

using namespace std;
//Declaration of a subroutine to be used in Main

void Rect_Rule(int N, float x[],float H,float rect, float F[])
{


for (int i=1; i<=N; i++){
    F[i] = (x[i]*x[i]) * sin(x[i]) * exp(x[i]*x[i]);
    x[i] = x[i]+H;
    rect = (F[i]*H)+rect;

}

cout<< "Rectangular Rule= "<< rect << endl;

}

int main()
{   

float H ,sum, rect ;
int N;
cout << "Input the number of subsections" << endl;
cin >>N;
float F[N];
float x[N];

float UPLMT=Pi;
float LWRLMT=0.0;
H = (UPLMT-LWRLMT)/N;
x = LWRLMT;

Rect_Rule(N,x,H,rect,F);     
return 0;
```

}

Comment: First welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Then two problems with your code: First C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead; Secondly, don't forget that array (and vector) indexes are *zero* based (i.e. an array of `N` elements have indexes from `0` to `N - 1`, inclusive).

Comment: Please note that `rect` is never initialized in `main` and so the local variable in the function isn't too. Besides, `x` is declared as an array (a VLA, which is wrong as already noted), but then `x = LWRLMT` tries to assign a `float` to it. What does you compiler says about that?